# cartesian join two R data.table and take the minimum

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two data.table R objects in R, streets and crashes. Below the descriptions:

```
head(streets)
  link_id      Lat     Long
1:  706815684 44.13163  9.84736
2:  572513298 46.87760 15.77544
3:  974462021 41.86439 16.04506
4:  906821226 43.30472 11.59198
5:  537724528 46.30359  7.59026
6: 1062652524 44.83993 19.08552
```

and

```
head(crashes)
ID_SX      Lat     Long
1: rca89123 45.35955  9.64950
2: rca89654 37.07544 15.28659
3: rca83674 44.42947  8.89526
4: lcg55792 38.08756 13.53466
5: lcg11992 41.81531 12.45126
6: iix21744 38.02655 12.88128
```

I would like to attach to crashes data set the link_id from the street data.framewhere is min the havesine distance (from R geospere package):

I was trying to use this code snippet, but it failed:

```
temp=crashes[streets(hdist=geosphere::distm(c(x.Long,x.Lat),c(i.Long,i.Lat),fun=distHaversine)),allow.cartesian=T]
```

Please note that streets data set is quite big (around 9Mln rows), whilst crashes is quite small (about 400 rows). I believe that, within R, only data.table could handle this efficenttly bu ti don't know how...

Thanks in advance for the support

Comment: I think it might be feasible like `crashes[, w := which.min(distfun(...)), by=ID_SX]` essentially a loop. Then `crashes[, closest_link := streets$link_id[w]]`. I don't know the details of your distance function, but I'm imagining you can get back a vector of distances. The Cartesian join doesn't seem to add anything except a large RAM requirement in this case.

Comment: Your code failed in what way? Error message? Wrong answers? Computer caught fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid a cartesian join of 9 M rows x 400 rows we can try to narrow the list of candidates using a *non-equi join*.

The idea is to narrow the "area of vicinity" for each crash site by picking those streets where `Lat` and `Long` are within a given delta around each crash site. Then, we only have to compute the havesine distance for those streets in the vicinity and find the minimum distance.

This is what I have tried with the provided data:

```
library(data.table)
# define +/- deltas for non-equi join ("area of vicinity")
d_lat <- 2.0
d_lon <- 2.0
streets[crashes[, .(ID_SX, Lat, Long,
                    # create lower and upper bounds
                    lb.lat = Lat - d_lat, ub.lat = Lat + d_lat, 
                    lb.lon = Long - d_lon, ub.lon = Long + d_lon)],
        # non-equi join conditions
        on = .(Lat > lb.lat, Lat < ub.lat, Long > lb.lon, Long < ub.lon), 
        .(link_id, x.Lat, x.Long, ID_SX, i.Lat, i.Long)][
          # compute distance for each row
          , hdist := geosphere::distm(c(x.Long,x.Lat),c(i.Long,i.Lat),fun=distHaversine),
          by = .(link_id, ID_SX)][
            # find minimum for each crash site
            , .SD[which.min(hdist)], by = ID_SX]
```

> ```
>       ID_SX   link_id    x.Lat   x.Long    i.Lat   i.Long     hdist
> 1: rca89123 706815684 44.13163  9.84736 45.35955  9.64950 137583.53
> 2: rca83674 706815684 44.13163  9.84736 44.42947  8.89526  82806.14
> 3: lcg11992 906821226 43.30472 11.59198 41.81531 12.45126 180146.65
> ```

Note that not for all crash sites a street is found within the given "area of vicinity". This is caused by the few number of streets.

For production purposes, `d_lat` and `d_lon` need to be adjusted (as small as possible to reduce run time and memory consumption but as large as necessary to find a street for every crash site).

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
streets <- fread(
  "i link_id      Lat     Long
1:  706815684 44.13163  9.84736
2:  572513298 46.87760 15.77544
3:  974462021 41.86439 16.04506
4:  906821226 43.30472 11.59198
5:  537724528 46.30359  7.59026
6: 1062652524 44.83993 19.08552", drop = 1L)
crashes <- fread(
  "i ID_SX      Lat     Long
  1: rca89123 45.35955  9.64950
  2: rca89654 37.07544 15.28659
  3: rca83674 44.42947  8.89526
  4: lcg55792 38.08756 13.53466
  5: lcg11992 41.81531 12.45126
  6: iix21744 38.02655 12.88128", drop = 1L)
```